# Get assets to compile when running via "activator run" in Play

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, sbt-web

I am using Sass as my CSS preprocesser, and I'm trying to have it run via the asset pipeline. I've tried implementing this sassTask as a source file task and as a web asset task, but I'm running into problems both ways.

If I run Sass as a source task (see below), it gets triggered during `activator run` when a page is requested and updated files are found upon page reloads. The problem I'm running into is that the resulting CSS files are all getting dumped directly into `target/web/public/main/lib`, instead of into the subdirectories reflecting the ones they are getting built into under the `resources-managed` directory. I can't figure out how to make this happen.

Instead, I tried implementing Sass compilation as a web asset task (see below). Working this way, as far as I can tell, `resources-managed` does not come into play, and so I compile my files directly into `target/web/public/main/lib`. I'm sure I'm not doing this dynamically enough, but I don't know how to do it any better. But the biggest problem here is that the pipeline apparently does not run when working through `activator run`. I can get it to run using `activator stage`, but I really need this to work in the regular development workflow so that I can change style files as the dev server is running, same as with Scala files.

I have tried combing through these forums, through the sbt-web docs, and through some of the existing plugins, but I am finding this process to be highly frustrating, due to the complexity of SBT and the opaqueness of what is actually happening in the build process.

Sass compilation as a source file task:

```
lazy val sassTask = TaskKey[Seq[java.io.File]]("sassTask", "Compiles Sass files")

sassTask := {
  import sys.process._
  val x = (WebKeys.nodeModules in Assets).value
  val sourceDir = (sourceDirectory in Assets).value
  val targetDir = (resourceManaged in Assets).value
  Seq("sass", "-I", "target/web/web-modules/main/webjars/lib/susy/sass", "--update", s"$sourceDir:$targetDir").!
  val sources = sourceDir ** "*.scss"
  val mappings = sources pair relativeTo(sourceDir)
  val renamed = mappings map { case (file, path) => file -> path.replaceAll("scss", "css") }
  val copies = renamed map { case (file, path) => file -> targetDir / path }
  copies map (_._2)
}

sourceGenerators in Assets <+= sassTask
```

Sass compilation as web asset task:

```
lazy val sassTask = taskKey[Pipeline.Stage]("Compiles Sass files")

sassTask := {
  (mappings: Seq[PathMapping]) =>
    import sys.process._
    val sourceDir = (sourceDirectory in Assets).value
    val targetDir = target.value / "web" / "public" / "main"
    val libDir = (target.value / "web" / "web-modules" / "main" / "webjars" / "lib" / "susy" / "sass").toString
    Seq("sass", "-I", libDir, "--update", s"$sourceDir:$targetDir").!
    val sources = sourceDir ** "*.scss"
    val mappings = sources pair relativeTo(sourceDir)
    val renamed = mappings map { case (file, path) => file -> path.replaceAll("scss", "css") }
    renamed
}

pipelineStages := Seq(sassTask)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that according to the documentation related to the [Asset Pipeline](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-web#asset-pipeline), a Source File task is a way to go:

> Examples of source file tasks as plugins are CoffeeScript, LESS and
>   JSHint. Some of these take a source file and produce a target web
>   asset e.g. CoffeeScript produces JS files. Plugins in this category
>   are mutually exclusive to each other in terms of their function i.e.
>   only one CoffeeScript plugin will take CoffeeScript sources and
>   produce target JS files. In summary, source file plugins produce web
>   assets.

I think what you try to achieve falls into this category.

#### TL;DR; - `build.sbt`

```
val sassTask = taskKey[Seq[File]]("Compiles Sass files")

val sassOutputDir = settingKey[File]("Output directory for Sass generated files")

sassOutputDir := target.value / "web" / "sass" / "main"

resourceDirectories in Assets += sassOutputDir.value

sassTask := {
  val sourceDir = (sourceDirectory in Assets).value
  val outputDir = sassOutputDir.value
  val sourceFiles = (sourceDir ** "*.scss").get
  Seq("sass", "--update", s"$sourceDir:$outputDir").!
  (outputDir ** "*.css").get
}

sourceGenerators in Assets += sassTask.taskValue
```

#### Explanation

Assuming you have sass file in a `app/assets/<whatever>` directory, and that you want to create css files in `web/public/main/<whatever>` directory, this is what you could do.

Create a task, which will read in files in the `app/assets/<whatever>` directory and subdirectories, and output them to our defined `sassOutputDir`.

```
val sassTask = taskKey[Seq[File]]("Compiles Sass files")

val sassOutputDir = settingKey[File]("Output directory for Sass generated files")

sassOutputDir := target.value / "web" / "sass" / "main"

resourceDirectories in Assets += sassOutputDir.value

sassTask := {
  val sourceDir = (sourceDirectory in Assets).value
  val outputDir = sassOutputDir.value
  val sourceFiles = (sourceDir ** "*.scss").get
  Seq("sass", "--update", s"$sourceDir:$outputDir").!
  (outputDir ** "*.css").get
}
```

This is not enough though. If you want to keep the directory structure you have to add your `sassOutputDir` to the `resourceDirectories in Assets`. This is because mappings in sbt-web are declared like this:

```
mappings := {
  val files = (sources.value ++ resources.value ++ webModules.value) ---
    (sourceDirectories.value ++ resourceDirectories.value ++ webModuleDirectories.value)
  files pair relativeTo(sourceDirectories.value ++ resourceDirectories.value ++ webModuleDirectories.value) | flat
}
```

which means that all unmapped files are mapped using an [alternative](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Mapping-Files.html#Alternatives) `flat` strategy. However the fix for it is simple, just add this to your `build.sbt`

```
resourceDirectories in Assets += sassOutputDir.value
```

This will make sure the directory structure is preserved.

Comment: Oh my god, dude, you have saved my life. What's so frustrating is that I spent 48 hours trying to figure this out, and I read the entire 48-page SBT tutorial. I suppose I may eventually have stumbled upon this behavior had I read the entire documentation, but I've got to say that all the "magic" going on behind the scenes in SBT is extremely frustrating.

Comment: @acjay I'm glad it helped you. Could you please accept the answer if you find it to be correct, so the question is not unanswered. Thanks.

Comment: You use `sourceGenerators`, but you probably mean `resourceGenerators`. Anyway, thank you for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: @lpiepiora, thank you so much for your answer. It helped me a lot!